# Is the word order in "know what's what" correct?

Tags: word-order

There's an expression: "to know what's what", as in: "He's been around for a long time - he knows what's what." (ref: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/know-what-s-what)).

But recently I started wondering: isn't it an [embedded question](https://writingcenter.gmu.edu/guides/word-order-in-statements-with-embedded-questions)? If so, shouldn't it actually be: "He's been around for a long time - he knows what what is."?

Comment: "what's what" is idiomatic, just like "which is which".

Comment: To be honest "idiomatic" mostly means "everyone's always been using it that way and that way only". Doesn't mean everyone hasn't always been wrong. (And yes, I know in natural languages if enough people have been making a mistake for long enough that mistake may eventually become the norm and therefore the correct way but that doesn't mean it wasn't a mistake initially).

Comment: Why do you presuppose it might be a mistake? It's precisely because it **is** an idiom that it has inversion. "What's what" means the true or real situation, whereas "What what is" seeks information about the referent of "what", which is of course meaningless.

Comment: 'He knows who is there/what is appropriate ....'

Comment: Compare "knows who is who", "knows which is which", etc.

Comment: It's not a question, it's an assertion.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify syntax, I will mark subjects with <sub>s</sub> in this answer. I will follow the usual convention of marking unacceptable sentences with a preceding *.

The word order in "He knows what<sub>s</sub> is what" is correct and does not have any subject-auxiliary inversion: the subject (the first *what*) comes before the auxiliary verb *is*, which comes before the predicative complement (the second *what*).

#### Syntax of interrogative clauses with multiple wh-words

"He knows what<sub>s</sub> is what" contains two wh-words in the same clause: one as the subject, and one as the predicative complement (as MarcInManhattan rightly notes).

The use of more than one wh-word in the same clause like this is not common in formal language, but when it occurs, more than one wh-word can't be put at the start of the clause, so any additional wh-word(s) beyond the first stay in place rather than undergoing wh-fronting. In this case, the predicative complement *what* stays in place (or "in situ"). This is normal English grammar for this context; it is not exceptional.

Per Glottopedia's article on [wh-in-situ](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Wh-in-situ):

> in languages with overt movement of one wh-element (like English), the other wh-elements stay in situ.

In the case of *what<sub>s</sub> is what,* since the clause has a wh-word as its subject, no subject-auxiliary inversion is possible, whether the clause is embedded or not (compare *Who<sub>s</sub> did it? I don't know who<sub>s</sub> did it,* not *Did who<sub>s</sub> it? or *I don't know did who<sub>s</sub> it?).

We do see subject-auxiliary inversion (with *do*-support if needed) in a non-embedded interogative with multiple wh-words where the first wh-word is not the subject: "What did he<sub>s</sub> put where?" And when embedded, we would have wh-fronting without subject-auxiliary inversion as "I don't remember what he<sub>s</sub> put where."

---

A priori, we might suppose that it should be syntactically possible to front the predicative complement, and leave the subject *what* in situ, which would result in it inverting with the verb. That would create "What is what?<sub>s</sub>" and when embedded, "What what<sub>s</sub> is". But I don't think this actually sounds natural to any speakers, so I don't think that is the structure that is actually used in the expression "know what's what".

In practice, there seem to be restrictions in interrogative clauses with multiple wh-words on which ones can be fronted.

These restrictions seem to be called "superiority effects"; here is a quote from literature studying that topic in a different context:

> for speakers that do allow wh-extraction of indirect objects,
> the predicted contrast does appear to hold, as shown in (85a-b).
>
> (85) a. ?? *Whom*<sub>i</sub> did John give t<sub>i</sub> what?
>
> b.* *What*<sub>i</sub> did John give whom t<sub>i</sub>?

([*Symmetry in Syntax: Merge, Move, and Labels*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jBCPPN2ptnEC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=wh-movement%20direct%20indirect%20object&source=bl&ots=Tp53fivL47&sig=bOvhB5__SGgZUDRuFVXAQYDDOIM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8gOeFttrKAhVW22MKHfM-BccQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=wh-movement%20direct%20indirect%20object&f=false), by Barbara Citko)

#### Other analogous examples

Other examples of the same type: "I don't know who<sub>s</sub> did what" and "I don't know what<sub>s</sub> goes where" (because the subjects are *who* and *what* respectively, the additional wh-words *what* and *where* remain unfronted).

Note that this word order is much more acceptable than "*"I don't know what who<sub>s</sub> did" or *"I don't know where what<sub>s</sub> goes."

Answer (score 0):

The word order is correct.

Other people may parse this differently, but one way is to consider "what's what" as a nominal clause (functioning as the object of "know"). The first "what" serves as the nominal clause's introductory word (subordinator). It also functions as the clause's subject, so the rest of the clause follows in regular order: the simple predicate ("is") comes next, followed by the predicate nominative (the second "what").

It is a bit unusual for both a subject and a predicate nominative to be wh-words, but in this case it is idiomatic.

By the way, it is also possible to write "he knows what what is", but in that case the first "what" would be the predicate nominative and the second "what" would be the subject. The meaning would therefore be slightly different and wouldn't seem to make much sense (although it might in some contexts).

Comment: Embedded questions like _He knows **what's what**, I wonder **what he meant, Why he did it** is a big mystery_ are one of the four complement clause types in English. It's one of the two tensed complement types, along with _that_ complements (the two untensed complement types are infinitives and gerunds). As you can see, such complement clauses can be subject or object, but only with certain verbs, which vary wildly. The embedded question type is distinguished by not performing subject-auxiliary inversion, the way real questions do.

Comment: No Marc: I agree _partly_ with JL: "what's what" is indeed a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "know". The meaning is "I know the answer to the question 'What's what?'". I disagree that it's an object: objects are virtually always noun phrases, but never clauses.

Comment: @BillJ It appears to me that except for terminology (e.g., whether to consider it an "object" or "complement"), your, my, and JL's analyses are entirely consistent with one another.

Comment: I don't think so: you said that it's a nominal clause, and that the first "what" is a subordinator, neither of which is the case. Crucially, you omitted to mention that it's an interrogative clause (embedded question).

Comment: @BillJ Those don't seem to be crucial issues to me. In either case, we begin with the wh-word, and then the rest of the clause follows in "typical" word order. There may be a philosophical difference, but the basic clause structure is similar. That's what I meant.

Comment: But the rest of the clause does not follow in typical word order since subordinate interrogatives do not normally have subj-aux inversion. It's precisely because it's an idiom, (whose word order is thus invariable) that it has inversion.

Comment: @BillJ When the subject is in first position, "typical" word order means that "the simple predicate ("is") comes next, followed by the predicate nominative" (as I wrote above). That is true whether you call it a nominal (content) clause, embedded question, subordinate interrogative, etc.

Comment: Subordinate interrogatives are marked by the combination of an initial interrogative word and uninverted order for what follows. This is what distinguishes them from main clauses. Thus, as the OP suggests, we would expect uninverted “what what is”. But the idiom “what’s what” is a fixed expression which, exceptionally, has inversion. Note that the first “what” is PC and the second is subject.

Comment: We could have cut to the chase much earlier had you indicated that you interpret this sentence's subject & PC differently! As I mentioned in my answer, the first "what" is the subject, so "what is what" is uninverted. Cf: "I know who steals the cookies." The wh-word in first position is the subject. The item in third position can't be the subject: *"I know whom steal the cookies." It's a bit more subtle with the copula, but if you think about it I think you'll see that it's correct.

Comment: I thought I did. Why should subordinate “what is what” be grammatically any different to subordinate “what is it” which unarguably has subj-aux inversion? In the first clause, the subject is the second “what” and the first “what” is PC. In the second clause the subject is “it”, and “what” is PC.

Comment: @BillJ Subordinate "what is it" doesn't have subj-aux inversion at all. As I said, it's not easy to see with the copula, but it's much easier to see with a transitive verb: "I know what pleases him" vs. *"I know what likes he". The introductory wh-word must be the subject, and the last word must be the complement.

Comment: Come to think of it, here's an example with a linking verb: "I know what becomes ice." The author clearly knows that water becomes ice, not that ice becomes something else.

Comment: Quote from an authoritative textbook: in the main clause "What are they?" "what" is PC, a non-subject. It is fronted and is accompanied by obligatory subj-aux inversion. The same applies if it is (exceptionally) used as a subordinate interrogative.

Comment: @BillJ This comment thread probably should have already been moved to chat, so let me try to simplify things: If you can convince me that "I don't know which stars are the Andromeda Galaxy" is wrong and should instead be ". . . is . . .", then I'll gladly concede the issue.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of that example. The simple fact is that in "What are they?", the subject is "they" and "what" is PC, thus that clause has inversion. Are you disputing this?

Comment: This was a confusing comment thread for me to read. I agree with MarcInManhattan that "what's what" has no inversion, and I agree with BillJ that "what is it" does have inversion (which is why I would use "what it is" in an embedded clause e.g. "...know what it is"). @BillJ, what do you think of my example "I don't know who did what"--rather than analyzing "what's what" as an exceptional "idiom", isn't it preferable to analyze it as having the same syntax as the above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because in short, you **know**, **what** is **what**. 'know what is what' is the correct order of words. No order of words would make any sense.

For example, **what^2** would be what you know *is*. **what^1** is regular usage.

Comment: Is there an 'other' missing in the last sentence?

Comment: @KillingTime I do not understand your question.

Comment: Try reading your first paragraph again. The final sentence contradicts the previous one.